# Submenu not showing on Android 2.3

Tags: android, submenu, android-actionbar-compat

I have an application with a Navigation Drawer and using Action Bar Compat and one of the options has an action bar button with a sub-menu. It is working fine on Android 3.0 and UP but not so good for Android 2.3:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/overflowButton"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/word_menu"
    yourapp:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/usedRemainingMenuItem"
            android:title="@string/menu_remaining"
            />
    </menu>
 <item>
```

What happens is that the app starts and I click on the button and it is fine. Then I choose another option from the Navigation Drawer, go back, and that button is no longer showing the sub-menu when clicked (I get the button action click on code).